# Shaking axes when animating

Tags: plotting

I have the code below to animate a point. During the animation, the axes are shaking. I have added PlotRange, and PlotRangePadding -> None. Still shaking. If I export the animation to a gif, the Axes will stop shaking. Can anyone help?

```
Animate[Show[
  Graphics[
   {
    PointSize[0.02],
    Point[{Cos[t], Cos[t]}]
    },
   PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
   Axes -> True
   ],
  PlotRange -> {{-2, 2}, {-2, 2}},
  PlotRangePadding -> None
  ], {t, 0, 10, 0.1}]
```

Comment: This works fine on v12.1.1, which version are you on?

Comment: This works fine on v. 12.0 on Win10-64 as well.

Comment: When folks are tried of asking what version number the OP is using, please check [is-there-a-way-to-remind-someone-posting-a-question-to-mark-the-version-number-i](https://mathematica.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2550/is-there-a-way-to-remind-someone-posting-a-question-to-mark-the-version-number-i) and may be try to give an answer to finally solve this problem.

Comment: mine is v12.0, Mac Os

Comment: try to add `ImagePadding`